# Centering Navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar, margins

I am trying to make my own navigation bar to get a better understanding of to create good navigation bars. The problem that I am having is centering my navbar. Now I know that using using margin-left: auto and margin-right: auto do usually do the trick and I have used that in the past but in this case no matter where I put these style elements my navbar doesn't seem to be centered. I have my body set to 100% and have provided my code below.
*Note: I have tried a container for my navbar and centering it but it still doesn't seem to work.

```
#navbar ul {
list-style-type:none;
color: #000;
padding: 0px;
text-align: center;
}
li:hover {
background-color: #cc2c32;
padding: 16px .1px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
.subcategory {
display: none;
width: 1031px;
height: 200px;
background-color: #cc2c32;
color: #03F;
position: absolute;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
margin-top: 15px;
}
li:hover .subcategory {
display: block;
}
#navbar {
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
background-color: #dee8ff;
float: left;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
#navbar ul li {
display: inline;
}
#navbar ul li a {
padding: 0 1.5em;
text-decoration: none;
}
ol {
list-style-type: none;
float: left;
display: block;
}
.contentwrapper {
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
height: 180px;
width: 200px;
background-color: inherit;
position: relative;
color: #2d4594;
}
a:link {
color: #2d4594;
text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
color: #2d4594;
text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
color: #2d4594;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

And my HTML is

```
<body>
<div id="navbar">
  <ul> 
    <li><a href="#">LinkHere</a>
        <div class="subcategory">
            <div class="contentwrapper">
            <ol>Hey</ol>
            <ol>Hey</ol>
            <ol>Hey</ol>
            <ol>Hey</ol>
            <ol>Hey</ol>
            <ol>Hey</ol>
            <ol>Hey</ol>
            <ol>Hey</ol>
            <ol>Hey</ol>
            <ol>Hey</ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">LinkHere</a>
        <div class="subcategory"></div>
    </li> 
    <li><a href="#">LinkHere</a>
        <div class="subcategory"></div>
    </li> 
    <li><a href="#">LinkHere</a>
        <div class="subcategory"></div>
    </li> 
    <li><a href="#">LinkHere</a>
        <div class="subcategory"></div>
    </li> 
    <li><a href="#">LinkHere</a>
        <div class="subcategory"></div>
    </li> 
    <li><a href="#">LinkHere</a>
        <div class="subcategory"></div>
    </li> 
    <li><a href="#">LinkHere</a>
        <div class="subcategory"></div>
    </li> 
    <li><a href="#">LinkHere</a>
        <div class="subcategory"></div>
    </li> 
</ul> 
</div> 
</body>
```

Comment: maybe a problem with float: left?

Comment: Did you set a width for the body tag?

Answer (score 2):

This is where inline-block is your friend.  Don't use floats.

```
#navbar {
    text-align: center;
}

#navbar > ul {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

Edit: added [fiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/QdahU/)

Comment: Note that this uses the (invalid) IE star hack. This is only needed if your site requires IE7 (and below) support. inline-block works correctly on IE8+. Also, the ">" child selector is supported in IE7+. So, in this case, the star hack would only get you as low as IE7, and not IE6, if you needed that kind of support.

If your site is using something like modernizr, you don't need to use hacks at all. The <html> element will gain classes that help you pinpoint browsers that are older than IE9, and you can build style rules that use valid CSS without hacks.

Comment: @wylander - thanks for the comment.  I was posting code for the widest support... which is IE7+ IMO (IE6 has been dead for quite some time and is irrelevant and not even worth mentioning).  If you don't need to support IE7, then remove the two lines beginning with stars.

Answer (score 1):

With float:left on #navbar you won't be able to use marin-left|right:auto trick. And if you just remove float, #navbar will be 100% wide which is not an option too.

Simple solutions:

1. Remove float from #navbar and use fixed width on #navbar with auto-margins on left and right.
2. Remove float from #navbar and use display:inline-block on #navbar and add text-align:center on its parent element. Set text-align:left back on #navbar li if necessary.
3. Remove float from #navbar and set display:inline-block for #navbar list items with text-align:center on #navbar.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **float: left** from your **#navbar{}** css. Then you may want to move the **background-color: #dee8ff;** to a child element and your maybe tweak the padding a little.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float:left` from `#navbar` and add `width: 1031px; margin:0 auto` (width is taken from subcategory class)

```
#navbar {
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
background-color: #dee8ff;
width: 1031px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin:0 auto
}
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/KLP8d/